# What is this following regular expression saying?

Tags: c#, regex

Just came across this following regular expression:

```
Regex.Match(feed.Element("description").Value, @"^.{1,180}\b(?<!\s)").Value
```

I know it says that starting with anything it should contain minimum 1 and maximum 180 characters `\b` stands for word boundaries. I didn't understand what is `\b` doing here. And then `(?<!\s)`. What is that expression doing? `?<!` stands for look behind and don't consume string. My guess is that it says look behind and it shouldn't end with space. I am not sure though. Can anybody clear these doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your expression [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uflg), this is a useful tool to test regular expressions.

I reduced the maximum length to 10 for test. So it looks like

```
^.{1,10}\b(?<!\s)
```

`(?<!\s)` is a negative look behind zero length assertion. That means it checks if the position before (on the left) is not a whitespace.

So, `^.{1,10}\b(?<!\s)` will match at the last word boundary in the first 10 characters of the string, but only if the left part or the word boundary is not a whitespace. This will not only match on "left word boundaries" (I think tripleee means the right side of the word), because word boundaries does not necessarily include whitespace.

A word boundary `\b` will match on the empty string between a word character (defined by the class \w) and a non word character \W.

That means `\b(?<!\s)` will match for example between "A$", "A ", "(A" or ".A". All of them have a word boundary in between and the left character is not a whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `(?<!\s)` makes sure that trailing whitespaces are not included in the match

It's easy to illustrate the following way. Change 180 to 10 in your example, so you do not need a really long test string:

```
^.{1,10}\b(?<!\s)
```

Now try to match the following string against it (note two spaces between two and three):

```
one two  three four
```

Your regular expression match won't include the two whitespaces between two and three. However if you remove the last part of your regular expression like this:

```
^.{1,10}\b
```

Then the two spaces after two *will* be included in the match.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the "not whitespace" assertion forces the \b to match left word boundaries only. So in other words, if the first 180 characters contain a word start anywhere after the first column, this matches. (The expression requires at least one arbitrary character before the match -- hard to say without context whether this is really correct, and what exactly it is supposed to accomplish.)

Comment: Why does the expression require at least one arbitrary character before the match? (What part of the regex expression mandates it?)

Comment: I don't think that you are correct. What are left word boundaries? I assume you mean the left side of a word. But this expression can match on the left and on the right side of a word, the only constraint is that the left character of the word boundary is not a whitespace.

Comment: @zespri: .{1,180} requires one or more characters (up to 180) before the word boundary.

Comment: @stema: you're right, the "not whitespace" would still allow for e.g. punctuation to the right of the word boundary. Anyway, the precision of expression is less than ideal, and like I wrote, without more context - such as knowledge about the expected input - we are left to guess the author's intentions.

Comment: We are talking here about `(?<!\s)` this is a look behind assertion, i.e. **it does not allow whitespace on the left**. The OP didn't ask if its correct, he wants to know what this expression is doing, that I can tell him. And as long as there is no specification, I don't say its correct or not.